# parse string to datetime using parse exact

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to parse a string to datetime using ParseExact but I keep failing..
I tried below but received an error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
string topA = "3/25/2016 12:00:00 AM";
DateTime d = new DateTime();
d = DateTime.ParseExact(topA, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", null);
```

Comment: Your format should be "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" as Soner Gönül noted. Probably it would be better to use DateTime.TryParse() instead with a European culture.

Comment: swap `dd/MM`. And `HH` is for 24 hours system, so 12:00:00 AM is invalid, use `hh` or 00:00:00 AM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your string, right format should be `M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` with preferable [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture).

```
string topA = "3/25/2016 12:00:00 AM";
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(topA, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: it worked! would it also work if I pass a month of 2 digits? how can I handle both situations?

Comment: @JuniorJohn `M` specifier _can_ parse two digits month actually. For example; `M` specifier is for `1` to `12` but `MM` specifier is for `01` to `12` (be aware leading zero for single digit)